# Update view after orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I created a blurred view on top of a scroll view (from a collection view) who is displaying on all the screen when user go to the settings but when orientation change when this blurview is active, it doesn't cover all the screen. I implemented the same function to update the frame size and origin when orientation change is catched but it still doesn't work.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    self.detailBlurView.removeFromSuperview()

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")

        detailBlurView.frame = myCollectionView.bounds
        self.myCollectionView.addSubview(detailBlurView)

    } else {
        print("Portrait")

        detailBlurView.frame = myCollectionView.bounds
        self.myCollectionView.addSubview(detailBlurView)
    }

    saveToCoreData()
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
    loadData()

}
```

I tried to remove the view from the superview and add it again after changing orientation but still not work.

Someone can tell me why it doesn't update the blurview frame and how to fix it please ?

Comment: You are setting the frame of the blur view to the bounds of your collection view, but I don’t see any code updating the frame of the collection view. Set the collection view frame in this method first and then set the blur view’s frame.

Comment: @Sparky the bounds property gets the correct frame also after orientation change. I already check this printing the collection view frame and the blur view frame, they are equals but blur view doesn't appear correctly